# Custom first page with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the package `fancyhdr` to format my footers and headers, with my name in the header and a *n of m* pages format for the footer. Like so:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[C]{Name}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

By default, the fancy page style only affects the pages after the first page. I know I can set the first page to the fancy page style using `\thispagestyle`, but I only want the first page to use the footer, not the header. Is there a way to create a custom style that just the first page will use?

Answer (score 98):

The `\fancypagestyle` command can be used to create custom styles:

```latex
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes horizontal header line
}
```

Then just use `\thispagestyle{firststyle}` on the first page, immediately after `\maketitle` (if that is used).

Comment: how to remove the horizontal bar that is still appearing on the first page ?

Comment: The horizontal bar can be removed using the code  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

Answer (score 37):

The best strategy is probably to redefine the `plain` page style that LaTeX applies automatically with `\maketitle` in the **article** class or with `\chapter` in the **report** and **book** classes:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
}
```

Comment: Do I need to explicitly put a `\label{LastPage}` on the last page?

Comment: @Matsmath No, that's done automatically by the `lastpage` package, which you should load.

Comment: Does not work for me in IEEE paper. Ony starts from second page. Had to add

Comment: You need to add the `lastpage` package for this. Put `\usepackage{lastpage}` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 12):

A [solution](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=9191) not constrained to cases where `\maketitle` is used and hence is perhaps more flexible:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
...
\rhead{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{\bfseries p1-title}{p2-and-following-title}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}

% \usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{}
\chead{}

\rhead{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{\bfseries The performance of Black Swans}{second page}}

\lfoot{From: K. Smith}
\cfoot{To: Jean A. Cory}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second of these pieces of code does not work, even when one corrects the obvious typos.  `\renewcommand` is not approriate here, and you should just use the command `\rhead` as in you first snippet.  There are formatting problems with you answer, and you should not just post a duplicate of another of your answers.  A comment with a link would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Marked the other Q&A as duplicate (and also deleted my answer there), and got rid of the "alternative" :-)

Comment: That's an improvement.  The first sentence of your answer still looks strange though and answers are better with a complete working document rather than code snippets.

Comment: @AndrewSwann added an MWE, changed the first sentence ;)

Answer (score 9):

It might be the case that the first page is not showing the desired `fancy` style because you are using `\maketitle` in it.  `\maketitle` automatically resets the pagestyle to `plain`.

In that case, simply adding `\pagestyle{fancy}` after the `\maketitle` command should solve the problem:

```
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}   % add this after maketitle
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: @cfr, yes, I did test it.  Note that different classes or packages my override `\maketitle` making it behave differently.

Comment: For `\documentclass{article}` this worked for me: `\maketitle \\
\thispagestyle{fancy}`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: Instead of hard-coding something into the header or footer, use something like this:

```
\fancyhead[<where>]{\myCurrentHead}
\fancyfoot[<where>]{\myCurrentFoot}
```

Then dynamically re-define `\myCurrentHead` and `\myCurrentFoot` content on the fly. The headers and footers will apply the most recently seen values, at the time the end of the page is reached. The values can be styled. And, the values can be empty, equivalent to an omitted header or footer (without changing the page style).

I have used this for a collection of short stories, where the author's name appears in verso header, and the story title in recto header. Change the current content at each new story start.

Might be problems if the size of content (such as line count) changes, but I have not tested that.