# Fancyheaders: how to turn off the page number on the first page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom first page with fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr)

I don't know how to turn off the page number on the first page of the following article with different headers on odd and even pages. I tried `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\begin{document}` but it doesn't work. The rest is OK.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \newcommand\shorttitle{The Short Title}
 \newcommand\authors{Author}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\shorttitle}
 \fancyhead[CE]{\authors}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}  
 \title{The Full Title}
 \author{Author}
 \maketitle
 \section{Section A}
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \section{Section B}
 \lipsum[3-10]
 \end{document}
```

ADDED. I don't want any header or footer on the first page.

ADDED 2: As [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74488/fancyheaders-how-to-turn-off-the-page-number-on-the-first-page#comment158817_74489) by Herbert writing `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}`after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` makes what I want.

EDIT: `\thispagestyle{empty}` is not needed. The revised code becomes

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \newcommand\shorttitle{The Short Title}
 \newcommand\authors{Author}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\shorttitle}
 \fancyhead[CE]{\authors}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \begin{document}
 \title{The Full Title}
 \author{Author}
 \maketitle
 \section{Section A}
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \section{Section B}
 \lipsum[3-10]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: didn't you read my last comment?

Comment: @Herbert  I did read. The `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}`after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`fixed the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @egerg This question may be an "exact duplicate of [Custom first page with fancyhdr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr)" for those who have a good knowledge of these matters, which I do not have. The existing answer was very useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\maketitle` uses pagestyle `plain`. Writing
 `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}`  after loading the package should help

Comment: I've written `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}`after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`. This removed the page number on the footer of the first page, but it has the undesired effect of making a header on the first page too, which I don't want.

Comment: then use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}`

Comment: Add also `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` if the rule is not wanted in the first page.