# Using fancyhdr to handle headers of different sizes

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to use `fancyhdr` in the `letter` document class to define a custom header for the first page only. I know that I can use `\fancypagestyle` to do this (as is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr)), but the problem is that my first-page header contains several rows, and I don't want the following pages to contain white space at the top that results from the 'missing' header. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You can use `\thispagestyle` command and a separate header for that. Also, change the `headheight` accordingly using `geometry`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted specific margins in my front-page, and following code helped me to specify margins for only that page. After `\begin{titlepage}` I put:

```
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
...
\pagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in}
```