# How to set document font to times new roman by command

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize, chapters

I wanted to know how to set font of a document to **Times New Roman** and size to 12 for text and for **Chapter Heading 14 only**, for the whole document. I don't want to use the `fontspec` package for this. Please help me out on this.

Comment: You should probably start to look at LaTeX-manual. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` helps with the font size of the document, `\usepackage{times}` with the font.

Comment: The `titlese` package helps you to change the size of the titles. You could add `\usepackage{titlesec}` to your document and redefine the chapters with `\titleformat{\chapter}{\large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}` or any other LaTeX size instead of `\large`.

Comment: And please also search on tex.SE before submitting a question, there's several answers regarding Times as a font, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math

Comment: I am asking about Times New Roman Font and for Chapter heading and none of these are helping sir.

Comment: Yes, they are, if your read the answer below; `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or the deprecated `\usepackage{times}` to get the LaTeX version of Times New Roman and redefine chapter headers to `\large` to have them 2.4 points bigger than the 12pt of the document.

Comment: Consider checking the [newtx](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx) package, which seems to be an improved `mathptmx` package: `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and `\usepackage{newtxmath}`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Let's construct what you're after:

1. 12 point text font

   For this you can pass a `12pt` option to the document class. For example, use

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}
   ```
2. Times New Roman font

   While there is no actual Times New Roman font in native LaTeX, the closest you'll get is by adding the [`mathptmx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx)

   ```
   \usepackage{mathptmx}
   ```

   or the [`newtx` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/newtx)

   ```
   \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
   ```

   to your document preamble. To check the actual font is included when doing this, see [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764).
3. 14 point chapter heading

   Under the `12pt` document class option, the closest to `14pt` is provided by the `\large` switch (see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)) - it'll actually be `14.4pt`, but that would be what the font has to offer. However, the current `\chapter` heading is set (by default) in a combination of `\huge` and `\Huge` (the former for the chapter heading - `Chapter X`, and the latter for the chapter title `A chapter`). So, we can patch the appropriate macro(s) (`\@makechapterhead` and `\@makechaptershead`) and substitute `\large` for `\huge` (with the aid of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   \makeatletter
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter
   \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter
   \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter*
   \makeatother
   ```

Here's a MWE that contains the above suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,mathptmx,etoolbox} % Or swap mathptmx with newtxtext,newtxmath

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{}{}% for \chapter*
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note how the `\section` title is now larger (set using `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`) than the `\chapter` title - a definite problem. However, you requested **Chapter Heading 14 only**.

Answer (score 7):

In order to have 12pt for your document - this works well

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
```

Use this at the start of the page. There is no predefined times new roman so you can use this instead -

```
\usepackage{Times} or \usepackage{mathptmx}
```

I was informed the times one is outdated and after trying the other one there were no visible changes so you can use any of them if you like.
Hope this helps

Comment: According to l2tabu this is a bad idea (the package `times`). This package is outdated and you should be replaced by `mathptmx`.

Comment: Thanks!! Great to hear from the most active members of the TeX community @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen

Comment: With your edit (and considering good style) this is an exact duplicate of the accepted answer and therefore probably more a comment.

Comment: It is better to use the packages `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and `'usepackage{newtxmath}`, prefer to avoid `mathptmx`