# How to write the title of an article in Times New Roman 14 pt bold?

Tags: fontsize

I need to write the title of my article in Times New Roman 14 pt bold. How do I write it? I don't know as I am new to latex.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153168/how-to-set-document-font-to-times-new-roman-by-command

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post your `MWE` in an executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`...

Answer (score 5):

Note that Times **New** Roman is not used in professional typography, because Times Roman is much more better. But this font is not free (it is sold by Adobe) but it does not matter: we have a good free alternative in TeX: TeXgyre Termes. You will don't see a difference (especially if you don't see differences between Times New Roman and Times Roman).

From PostSript epoch of fonts (90s) there was free alternative to PostSript Times Roman too. It was NimbusRoman from URW used in Ghostscript. Note that the answer from WinnieNotThePooh uses `\usepackage{times}` and this package loads NimbusRoman in fact.

My example uses OpTeX and Termes:

```
\fontfam [Termes]
\def \_titfont {\typosize[14/]\bf}

\tit This is a title

This is text.
\bye
```

Note that there is another difference (not only Times New Roman contra Termes). The dimension "14 pt" means typically "14 *(1/72) in" but it is "14 *(1/72.27) in" in TeX world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via  Series}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
\and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}

\begin{document}
\bfseries  % command which make all in bold
\maketitle %            | 
%                       |
%                       | 
\clearpage%             |
\normalfont  % till this command
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
```