# Urgent: Typing a simple equation

Tags: equations

Requesting help urgently...
Would anyone please be able to let me know a way to type this simple equation in Latex, properly, without the obvious errors? I have used the following code (please see the code below), however, it produces the output with some obvious errors (please see the output image attached) such as;

1. the entire equation is in italics and another font. Should be changed to regular Times New Roman text 12pt, non-italicized.
2. words are conjoined. In the code, the words are separated, however that does not translate to the output and all words are joined together. How can I change the code to add space between two words? these should be not conjoined.

[image]

The code is here;

```
\begin{equation}
\underset{[\mathrm{Cells/uL}]}{Absolute Count} = \frac{Cell Count \times eBead Volume}{eBead Count \times Cell Volume} \times eBead Concentration
\end{equation}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure such formulas are meaningful. Anyway, you want to use text and not math for the words.

And microliters, not uL.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underset{[\mathrm{Cells/\unit{\micro\liter}}]}{\textup{Absolute Count}} =
\frac{\textup{Cell Count} \times \textup{eBead Volume}}
     {\textup{eBead Count} \times \textup{Cell Volume}}
\times \textup{eBead Concentration}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the global document font to Times

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underset{[\mathrm{Cells/\unit{\micro\liter}}]}{\textup{Absolute Count}} =
\frac{\textup{Cell Count} \times \textup{eBead Volume}}
     {\textup{eBead Count} \times \textup{Cell Volume}}
\times \textup{eBead Concentration}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Times New Roman in native LaTeX. The closest you can get by loading `mathptmx` (see: [How to set document font to times new roman by command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153168/how-to-set-document-font-to-times-new-roman-by-command))

You can add text in a math formula by the command `\text`. See the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \underset{\text{Cells/uL}}{\text{Absolute Count}} = \frac{\text{Cell Count}\;  \times\; \text{eBead Volume}}{\text{eBead Count} \; \times \; \text{Cell Volume}} \; \times\; \text{eBead Concentration}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, there are much better alternatives to `mathptmx`.

Comment: Why is `newtxtext` better than `mathptmx`?

Comment: These are both perfect answers. Thank you so much egreg and bmv for your quick responses.

Comment: For several reasons: `newtx(text,math)` are actively maintained; `mathptmx` is a 25 year old hack.