# How to have No fancy header in first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

I can remove the top bar but not only in the first page. 
Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30228/13173
\newsavebox{\myheadbox}% Heading storage box
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{School}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Output: top bar visible in the first page.

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit

Comment: Something like `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

brian-ammon's answer; place it in the beginning of the first page

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Output: works!