# Missing header: (\rhead not shown)

Tags: fancyhdr, missing

I want to create a document with both header and footer. So far the footer has been working fine but not the header, which is missing for some reason. Do anyone have a clue as to why it happens?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%opening
\title{Example}

\usepackage[margin = 1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Not working}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\bd}{\textbf}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\bibliographystyle{APA}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Actually the footer isn't working either, because the page number is in the centre, not right. The point is that when using `\maketitle` with the `article` class the page style `plain`is used. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30230/82917

Comment: Now that you mention it, I didn't recognize the footer was centered. I will check out the link you included. Thanks

Comment: @Rei -- welcome -- the answer below should work -- have alook -- I have not used bibliography so commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%opening
\title{Example}

\usepackage[margin = 1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Page \thepage}
        \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Not Working}
}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
%   \bibliographystyle{APA}
%   \bibliography{bibliography.bib}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I suppose the way to go here is to overwrite the `plain` style with your `firststyle` and apply it to the paper, is that right?

Comment: first option have a look at the documentation -- second this site has numerous examples of `fancyhdr` -- you can search in the bar above -- in case of specific problem please revert -- incidentally you can name your style anything as example `\fancypagestyle{mystyle}`  and then initialise or call that style after `begin document`