# How to write rhead only on the first page - what is wrong with the code?

Tags: atbegshi

How to write rhead only on the first page? Why does this code not work?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead{}
\chead{}


\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\rhead{AAAAAA}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\rhead{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
AAAAAAAA
\newpage
AAAAAAAAA
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586471/missing-header-rhead-not-shown/586473#586473

Comment: Would it be possible somehow with \AtBeginShipoutFirst{\rhead{}}?

Comment: your code writes only on the first page -- what is the problem

Comment: I do not know, I added the result to my question.

Comment: My impression is that you want to *remove* the right header in the first page, is this correct?

Comment: I want to remove the right header on the second page. I would like to have it only on the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression is that you want to *suppress* the header in the first page.

You can use a conditional in the code for the right header (but this will keep the rule).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\ifnum\value{page}=1 \else AAAAAA\fi}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}

AAAAAAAA

\newpage

AAAAAAAAA

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, issue `\thispagestyle{plain}` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you very much