# Customize First Page Style Fancyhdr: Error ! File ended while scanning use of \f@nch@pagestyle

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I tried to answer my question with [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/custom-first-page-with-fancyhdr), but I get error messages and can’t figure it out.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[authordate,autocite=inline,backend=biber, natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}
    
\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


%%% headers and footers
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OR]{The Prime Minister’s Prerogatives}
\fancyhead[EL]{Louis Vigneras}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\fancypagestyle{first}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\}%
}

\author{Author}
\title{The Prime Minister’s Prerogatives}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Thext}
\thispagestyle{first}

Text....

\end{document}
```

Messages/log:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \f@nch@pagestyle.
```

Any idea what this is, and how to fix it?

Comment: Delete the last \  in `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\}%` to `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%` ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I don’t know how I didn’t spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo issue as pinpointed by @Mensch:
Delete the last \ in `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\}%` to \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% ...