# Custom template creation

Tags: texworks, custom

I am interested in creating a custom templet as shown below
Page 1

[image: Page 1 layout]

Page 2
[image: Page 2 layout]

but currently, I am using the following code which is not producing the required templet
Any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % For including images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % For generating placeholder text. You can remove this in your final document.

% Page setup
\geometry{margin=1in}

% Define the page style
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{ % Header for the first page
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}  % Left logo on the first page
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}  % Right logo on the first page
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Remove horizontal line in header
}

\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{ % Header for subsequent pages
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}}  % Subject as header on other pages
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Remove horizontal line in header
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{firstpage} % Apply the first page header style
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{0cm}  % Remove the top space
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}  % Left top logo
        \hfill  % Right-align the following text
        \textbf{Internal Report}  % Centered text
        \hfill  % Right-align the following text
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}  % Right top logo
        \vspace{1cm}
        \hrule  % Horizontal line
        \vspace{1cm}
        \begin{flushleft} % Begin left-aligned block
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X r@{}} % Left-aligned text and right-aligned text
            To: Name1 & Date: \today \\ % Add the date right-aligned next to "To"
            \vspace{1\baselineskip}  % One line spacing
            From: Name2 \\
            \vspace{1\baselineskip}  % One line spacing
            Cc: Name3 \\
            \vspace{1\baselineskip}  % One line spacing
            Subject: Title
        \end{tabularx}
        \end{flushleft} % End left-aligned block
        \vspace{1cm}
        \hrule  % Second horizontal line
    \end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%\pagestyle{otherpages} % Apply the header style for subsequent pages

\section*{Summary}  % This is the "Summary" section
%\hrule  % Start the section right after the second horizontal line
Summary content goes here.

%\newpage % Start a new page

\section*{Introduction}  % This is the "Introduction" section
Your report content goes here.

\subsection*{Subsection}  % This is a subsection without a number
More content.

\section*{Conclusion}  % This is the "Conclusion" section
Concluding remarks.

\end{document}
```

The output from the present code is as followa
Page 1
[image]

and page 2
[image]

Comment: You need three tick marks before and after code blocks, not just one.  Could you elaborate on the current shortcomings, so that we don't have to examine the images and guess?

Comment: The main difference I see is that `{titlepage}` is causing a page break where I think you don't want it.  But I'm not sure if that's the problem, or something else, or if there are multiple problems.

Comment: Note we can't reproduce the problem because only you have access to the logo images your code requires. You could use e.g. `example-image` instead to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Basic idea:

- write your own documentclass `tmplt.cls`
- use it inside your main document `main.tex`
- ignore some minor adjustment hickups for now
- ignoring all font issues, focus on pdflatex

[image: result]

#### Addressing your major problems

- pagebreak after `\maketitle`: use `\tmplttitle{}` instead (in tmplt.cls)
- however, there certainly is a solution to handle the extra pagebreak from the `titlepage environment`
- header-problems: adapted [this solution from 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122379/245790)

To stimulate your ideas about typesetting I used two minipages, while your table will work fine as well. Kindly watch (and use yourself) all those `%` at the end of lines inside `\newcommand`: This keeps unwanted insertion of spaces away, hence unwanted layout shifts.

```
% ~~~ create your own title page ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\tmplttitle[0]{%
{{\parindent0pt% localized: disabling indenting of first line
    % ~~~ you could use your tabularx approach as well ~~~
...
    \bigskip%
    \hrule%
}}}
```

Very straightforward the content of some fancy-fields depend on the page (number), using `\ifthenelse{cond}{if-case}{else-case}`, see link above.

```
\fancyhead[C]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}%
                {\raisebox{.25in}{\large{Internal Report}}}%
                {\subj{}}}
```

#### Handling .cls files

During development it's ok to have the `.cls` in the same directory as your `main.tex`.

To test my solution, just copy the code from the very end into a `main.tex` and a `tmplt.cls` inside a fresh directory.

Once done you may want to move the class to the [TEXMF root](https://miktex.org/kb/texmf-roots), AND update your Latex-distribution about this, e.g. via your [MikTex console](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/configuring.html). After that you can use `\documentclass{tmplt}` from anywhere as usual with other classes. (And don't forget to provide a documentation there, too. You'll need it yourself, sooner or later.)

#### What this tmplt.cls provides

Default names:

```
% ~~~ default names, subject, date ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\nameto[0]{Name 1}
...
```

Default images, which you'd change as needed for your standard:

```
% ~~~ default for images ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\imleft[0]{example-image}
\newcommand\imright[0]{example-image-duck}
```

Shortcuts to relevant structures, just for convenience:

```
% ~~~ shortcuts to relevant sections ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\concl[1]{\section*{Conclusion}#1}
\newcommand\intro[1]{\section*{Introduction}#1}
\newcommand\summ[1]{\section*{Summary}#1}
```

Said replacement for `\maktitle` and page-dependent handling of your headers.

#### Using tmplt.cls in main.tex

- specify this class
- overwrite defaults using `\renewcommand`
- put summary, intro, conclusion
- use standard Latex in between

Here's a basic scheme, which you might save for reuse ...

```
\documentclass{tmplt}
\renewcommand\mydate{11/04/2023}
\begin{document}
 \tmplttitle{}
 \summ{enter here}
 \intro{enter here}
...
 \concl{ener here}
\end{document}
```

So if you have a dedicated `/img` directory, you might overwrite like this:

```
\renewcommand\imleft{img/logo}
```

#### Code

tmplt.cls:

```
% see e.g. "The Latex Companion", Mittelbach et. al.

% ~~~ 1) identification ~~~~~~~~~~
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
  \ProvidesClass{tmplt}[2023/11/11]

% ~~~ 2) initial code ~~~~~~~~~~
%        instead of \usepackage call
  \RequirePackage{ifthen}
  \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
  \RequirePackage{graphicx}


% ~~~ 3) declaration of options ~~~~~~~~~~

% ~~~ 4) execution of options ~~~~~~~~~~

% ~~~ 5) package loading ~~~~~~~~~~
  \LoadClass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}%       use as base class
  \RequirePackage[%showframe,% uncomment showframe to check layout settings
    margin=1in,top=1.8in,headheight=1.5in]{geometry}


% ~~~ 6)  main code ~~~~~~~~~~
% ~~~ these ones can be useful for horizontal and vertical alignment ~~
\newcommand\hs[1]{\hspace{\stretch{#1}}}
%\newcommand\vs[1]{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}}

% ~~~ default names, subject, date ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\nameto[0]{Name 1}
\newcommand\namefrom[0]{Name 2}
\newcommand\namecc[0]{none}
\newcommand\subj[0]{This is the title}
\newcommand\mydate[0]{\today{}}

% ~~~ default for images ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\imleft[0]{example-image}
\newcommand\imright[0]{example-image-duck}

% ~~~ shortcuts to relevant sections ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\concl[1]{\section*{Conclusion}#1}
\newcommand\intro[1]{\section*{Introduction}#1}
\newcommand\summ[1]{\section*{Summary}#1}

% ~~~ create your own title page ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\tmplttitle[0]{%
{{\parindent0pt% localized: disabling indenting of first line
    % ~~~ you could use your tabularx approach as well ~~~
%   \hrule%
    \bigskip%
  % ~~~ typesetting left column ~~~~~
  \begin{minipage}{8cm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}%
        To:     & \nameto{}\\%
        From:   & \namefrom{}\\%
        Cc:     & \namecc{}\\%
        Subject:& \subj{}\\%
    \end{tabular}%
  \end{minipage}%   
  \hs{1}%
  % ~~~ typesetting right entry ~~~~~~~~
  \begin{minipage}{3cm}%
    \mydate{}%
  \end{minipage}%
    \bigskip%
    \hrule%
}}}

% ~~~ taking care of headers and footers ~~~~~~~~~~
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{\imleft}}

% ~~~ adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122379/245790 ~~~
\fancyhead[C]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}%
                {\raisebox{.25in}{\large{Internal Report}}}%
                {\subj{}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{%
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{\imright}%
    }%
    {\thepage}}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{tmplt}%  <<< work with your template
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ~~~ overwrite tmplt variables as needed ~~~~~
\renewcommand\nameto{Dr. Cooper, Dr. Hofstadter}
\renewcommand\subj{This is the title, in a modified version}
\renewcommand\mydate{11/04/2023}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 % ~~~ 1) show the title pages as defined in tmplt ~~~
 \tmplttitle{}

 % ~~~ 2) put your summary, from tmplt ~~~
 \summ{Something short.\\%
    Or perhaps not so short. Or even a bit more. The sky's the limit. Whatever limits the sky.%
 }
 
 % ~~~ 3) put your introduction, from tmplt ~~~
 \intro{\lipsum[10]}
 
 % ~~~ 4) use standards here ~~~
     \section*{Where it all started}
     Let's reflect the starting point a little.
     
     \subsection*{Where we were}
     \lipsum[12]
     
     \subsection*{Where we wanted to go}
     \lipsum[13]
     
     \section*{And so the story went}
     \lipsum[1-5]
 
 % ~~~ 5) put your conlcusion here, from tmplt ~~~
 \concl{Whatever it took.}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for creating a .cls file, now I have a learned a bit on creating oue own class. It is working as intended.

Comment: Fine : ) Please feel free to like and accept my answer.